# How to make a word wrap in the text of an element (Text, Label, displayField) with ExtJS 4.2.1?

Tags: extjs, text, line-breaks, word-wrap

Must show a text that is greater than the component in which it is inserted. Currently, the text does not wrap automatically.

[image]

I've tried using the following components: Text, Label and Display Field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a text that contains white space? A single word that is too long won't be wrapped ever, but multiple shorter, space-delimited words maybe will, depending on the component you use.

If you want to show a long text, use a `container` and put the text into the `html` configuration, and it will auto-wrap.

The components you named also have their usage, but not for simple long text:

- `text` is from the `draw` package, and good for specialized formatting.
- `displayfield` is good inside a form whenever you want to display (read-only) some value that is part of the record that you load into the form. `displayfield` won't wrap at all - try `textareafield` with `readonly` configuration for that.
- `label` is good as the label of a form field, but only if used via the `labelable` mixin, which does most of the work. A `label` should make its content wrap around if you provide a fixed width or maxWidth, but it does not automatically adhere to the parent object layout.

Comment: I set the html of the container, but the text did not break

Comment: In fact, it worked. The problem was what you reported earlier. The "word" was too long.

Answer (score 2):

you can simply add styles to extjs components (you can use any of them):

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

There are some ways to apply custom css styles to ext's elements

```
style: {
  "word-wrap": 'break-word'
}
```

Also you can do this:

```
Ext.get('txtElement').setStyle('word-wrap', 'break-word');
```

Comment: please can you show the code of this box? how you create? apply this css?

Comment: Man `xtype: text` behaves like `pre` tag, you have to use `\n` to break lines otherwise use different types. Just your question was confusing as I thought you just wanted to break looong text in any case..